# PPA without upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa

I just installed smartgithg via ppa:eugenesan/ppa. After an upgrade and restart the whole window style got broken and I can't switch to my preferred keyboard layout. May be some other errors occured as well.

The problem is that this ppa has tons of packages that my system alter in a way I don't want them to do. I just want to install smartgithg and get updates via apt.

So the question is: how to add ppa and just install one package and may be some requirements but do not use this ppa for upgrades?

For now I ppa-purged the ppa. The system is now working again. I'm wondering why smartgithg is still installed. Anyways I won't get updates for it..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since `smartgithg` is not in the Ubuntu repositories, something like this in `/etc/apt/preferences` should do (untested, however) :

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "XX.archive.ubuntu.com"
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: origin "security.ubuntu.com"
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

You are giving priority >= 1000 to all packages from the Ubuntu repos (change according to your archive mirror, of course). This means that Apt will always prefer packages from the repos, even if the version is lower than packages available from other sources (in your case, the PPA).